# How to find what power of a number is of another number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

In the equation, $a=b^x$, Is there an easy way to find the value of $x$ using a calculator (Other than trying multiple $x$ values)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a,b>0$ we have

$$a=b^x \iff \ln a = x \ln b.$$

can you proceed ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is $\log_b(a)$. if your calculator doesn't have an option to do different bases, you can use change of base and do $\frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)}$.